# diagonal check for connect 4

Tags: python, diagonal

this is my first time asking a question.
I am trying to make a connect 4 python game with the height of the table that can be modified by the players but I am having problems with checking the diagonals since the height can changed. Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Could you please show something you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

try this function it will check if the user wins or not but instead of checking the whole board it will check the last play position you will pass row and col position of the last play

```
def check_diagonal(row,col):
    # First diagonal
    for i in range(-min(3, row, col), min(1, 3-row, 4-col)):
        if self.grid[row+i][col+i] == self.grid[row+i+1][col+i+1] == self.grid[row+i+2][col+i+2] == self.grid[row+i+3][col+i+3]:
            return True
    # Second diagonal
    for i in range(-min(3, row, 6-col), min(1, 3-row, col-2)):
        if self.grid[row+i][col-i] == self.grid[row+i+1][col-i-1] == self.grid[row+i+2][col-i-2] == self.grid[row+i+3][col-i-3]:
            return True
    return False
```